# Cannot go on Internet from my remote location over vpn connection

Tags: firewall, openvpn, pfsense

Many information exists on this forum and Internet but I just can't filter out the solution for me.
My setup is quite simple. I just installed pfSense and configured OpenVPN server on it. I downloaded the client with the "Client Export" tool and installed it on my laptop (Windows). Nothing more.
Everything works fine except one thing. When I use my client on the Windows laptop on a remote location and I am connected successfully to my pfSense box at home, I cannot go on Internet. I can rdp to a desktop pc at home and go on Internet via that way though. But why can I not just open a browser at my remote location and throw my http requests through the tunnel and get the requested webpage on my browser? I'd like to go on (https://www.whatismyip.com) and see the public IP address from my home.
 
 Do I have to tweak my nat and firewall rule settings? Till now I just have "auto created" nat rules and firewall rules. Should I learn more about PIA? I saw an explanation about giving your OpenVPN an interface (OPT1).
Also I can find much info about site-to-site vpn's but that is not my setup here. I have one pfSense at home and want to connect to it through OpenVPN client and go on Internet.
Thanks for the support.

Comment: Did you enable IP forwarding in your kernel?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use your pfSense machine as gateway you must ensure the following two things.

1. Forwarding is enabled.
2. NAT/Masquerade rule is configured for the packets which are coming in from openvpn tun/tap interface and leaving the internet/external interface.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to update this one...
Solution:
My home router (the pfSense) his local IP is 192.168.1.1. Classic. But the local IP of the modem I used on my remote location was also 192.168.1.1. The last one I changed to 192.168.0.1. And now when connected through OpenVPN I can open my webbrowser, go on whatismyip and see the public IP adress from home.

So when I had the problem I assume that when I opened my webbrowser and tried to go on Internet the traffic got confused somewhere when coming back to my laptop at the remote location.